# How to test with jest for a custom component that implements control value accessor

Tags: angular, jestjs

I am using a component that is a cdk which is a third party and I do not know how it is implemented but I need to test the component in Jest in angular. That component has implemented control value accessor because I can put a formControlName to that tag.

```
<customer-file formControlName = "cust">
   <input type="file" randomStuff (onChange) ="checkFile()" />
</customer-file>
```

Test spec file

```
describe('customerFileComponent', () => {
  let component: customerFileComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<customerFileComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [customerFileComponent],
      imports: [FormModule, ReactiveFormsModule, ButtonModule, NoopAnimationsModule],
    }).compileComponents();

  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(customerFileComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.cust= new FormGroup({
      cust: new FormControl(null),
    });
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

Error - Issue with the test

```
 Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
        --> starting at object with constructor 'Object'
        |     property 'element' -> object with constructor 'Object'
        |     property 'publicProviders' -> object with constructor 'Object'
        |     property 'ɵNgNoValidate_109' -> object with constructor 'Object'
        --- property 'parent' closes the circle
        at stringify (<anonymous>)
```

What do we need to do to test this as this is just a barebone test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create wrapper component to properly test your `CVA component`. Then you have access to your `FormGroup` parent values and nested actual testing component.
For example:

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <ng-container [formGroup]="formGroup">
      <customer-file formControlName="custom"></customer-file>
    </ng-container>
  `
}) class CustomTestWrapper {
  @ViewChild(CustomerFileComponent, { static: true }) public customerFileComponent: CustomerFileComponent;

  formGroup = new FormGroup({
    custom: new FormControl(),
  });
}
```

and next:

```
describe('CustomComponent', () => {
  let component: CustomTestWrapper;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<CustomTestWrapper>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [CustomComponent, CustomTestWrapper],
      imports: [ReactiveFormsModule],
    })
    .compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CustomTestWrapper);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component.customerFileComponent).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should set value', () => {
    const newValue = 'hey here!';

    component.formGroup.patchValue({
      custom: newValue,
    });

    expect(component.customerFileComponent.control.value).toBe(newValue);
  });
});
```

And so on.

Comment: Exactly as @Anton said, the `cust` variable must be part of a parent component.